# save user actions?

Tags: php, mysql, user-interface

i want to save logged in users actions so when they visit the page again they don't have to do the same thing again eg. what list values they chose or what page they were on before they logged out.

i dont want to save it as cookies because i want them to be unchanged even if he switch computer. should i save these kind of information in another table in in the database?

should i have an ID column? or just and USER_ID as the unique id column and then the settings columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you'll have to put them in a table dedicated to options and I suppose you could safely ignore the id column and have just the user_id as a foreign key.